# pdf-download-button doesn't trigger a event if you press on it

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a Angular application in 6 and I have two buttons for back and one for download pdf. But the download pdf doesnt work, I mean the cursor doesnt change to a hand when you hover over the button

Googled a lot

This are the two buttons:

```
  <a  *ngIf="pdfUrl" class="button pdf-download-button" [href]="getPDFUrl()" [download]="getPDFTitle()">Download PDF</a> This one doesnt work

  <button type="button" class="button pdf-back-button" (click)="handleBack()" >Ga terug</button> So this one works
```

That you can trigger the button.

```
getPDFUrl() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.pdfUrl);
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: Can you try download=“Test.txt” to see if it is working

Comment: your a tag has 'button' class, I assume this is why you don't see the right cursor.

Comment: the problem is , that I cant trigger the button

Comment: Please post getPDFUrl() code

Comment: If the cursor doesn't change with mouse hover, then it's an issue with CSS. Can you download the pdf file by clicking on the button (although it seems like not clickable, just try clicking it)?

Comment: Yes, but you can only click in the upper corner. But I think it is solved. Thank you